# Code Not Running, using multiple threads to sum up individual rows and columns

Tags: java, multithreading

> My code is set up to take an array.
>
> Once the array has been imported,

I have created:

- Threads to get the some of the rows
- A thread to get the sum of the columns.

I am have trouble getting the created threads (in the I have created: part.) to run now, and I don't know what the problem could be.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class ThreadEx{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("rowcolumn.txt"));
        int myArray[][] = new int [256][256];
        int j = 0;
        int k = 0;
        while(scanner.hasNextInt()){
            myArray[j++][k++] = scanner.nextInt();
        }
        ShowChar s = new ShowChar();
        ShowNum i = new ShowNum();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(s);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(i);
        t1.start();     t2.start();
        s.start();      i.start();
    }


    int row = 0;
    int col;
    int rowSum = 0;
    int colSum = 0;
///////////////////////////////
class ShowChar extends Thread{
    for(col = 0; col<5;col++)  {
        for( row = 0; row<5; row++)  {
          rowSum = rowSum + myArray[row][col];
        }
        System.out.println("Sum of row "  + rowSum);
        rowSum=0;  
    }
}

class ShowNum extends Thread{

    for(row=0; row<10;row++)  {
        for(col = 0; col<10; col++)  {
           colSum = colSum + myArray[row][col];
        }
        System.out.println("Sum of column " + colSum);
        colSum=0;
    }
}
```

Comment: *I'm having trouble* is a story, not a problem description.

Comment: Please be specific on what you want to achieve and what issues you are facing? Check this out for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: To start with, The myArray is a method level variable, hence would not be visible in your thread classes. Modify the constructor to accept myArray as a parameter. Also,. you need add your code inside run() method of Thread classes.